# want to send array of ng-repeat to controller fastest way in MVC with angular, how?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, get, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have Regular Form that I fill in ng-repeat , after filling everything I want to send it with $http.get to my controller.

the problem I couldn't  find a way to send array.

can anyone help ?

Comment: What specific problems are you having? please show what you tried. Sending an array is as simple as sending primitives

Comment: i have ng-repeat with 10 variables (x.Mail,x.FirstName and more), and i need to send it to the controller